# Cassandra unset int becomes 0 when converted to Option in Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I have a cassandra row

```
slug | logo | name | priority
------+------+------+----------
test | null | Test |     null
```

I am using the datastax java driver to query this result and then mapp the `Row` to a Scala case class :

```
Brand(r.getString("slug"), r.getString("name"), Option(     r.getInt("priority") )  ,Option( r.getString("logo")))
```

The result should have been :

```
Brand(test,Test,None,None)
```

But I get this :

```
Brand(test,Test,Some(0),None)
```

Both `priority` and `logo` fields were not set while inserting. If I simply print the row, I get the correct result :

```
[Row[test, NULL, Test, NULL]]
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: well, an `Int` in scala is `AnyVal` not `AnyRef` thus it cannot be `null` (like `int` in java) so this is why you get your null int as 0/ Maybe desing of your db is wrong? Maybe you should use something else to denote missing/unknown priority like -1, or use strings, or maybe there is some other method that this api provides, but I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Lukasz, I can see the problem now.

Since I can not change the data model I ended up putting a `isNull` check while mapping.

```
Brand(r.getString("slug"), r.getString("name"),(if( r.isNull("priority") ) None else Some(r.getInt("priority")) ), Option( r.getString("logo")))
```